# After Upgrading JQuery Mobile to 1.0.1, Code Isn't Working

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

This works just fine, with JQM 1.0a1:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Main Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header"><h1>Main Page</h1></div>
<div data-role="content"><p><a href="#map">Map</a></p></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#map').live("pagecreate", function() {
        initialize(1.359,103.818);
    });


    function initialize(lat,lng) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    }


</script>

<div id="map" data-role="page" data-theme="b" class="page-map" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
<div data-role="header"><h1>Map Page</h1></div>
<div data-role="content" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0;"> 
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the same using JQM 1.0.1 (http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js) doesn't show the map at all. I tried using `$('#map').on` and `"pageinit"` to no avail.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**: same behavior with JQuery 1.6.3

**UPDATE2**: by giving an absolute size (eg height: 200px; width: 200px;) to the #map-canvas div, it works fine.

Comment: I think you're using jQM Alpha 1? Much has changed since then as jQM have released a2, a3, a4, RC1, RC2, 1.0 and now 1.0.1 I would read over the Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/ and update you code with the newer implementation. Also as of 1.0.1 jQM support jQuery 1.6.4, I think jQM 1.1 will support jQuery 1.7.x but not positive on that

Comment: I did read the Docs, but still I can't get it to work. Both `pageinit` and `pagecreate` are triggered correctly, so I don't know where else to look.

Comment: No. But I noticed with Firebug that the map is actually loaded but not displayed. I guess it's a CSS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the question's update, by giving an absolute size (eg `height: 200px; width: 200px;`) to the `#map-canvas` div, the problem is solved.